# Non-informative prior for integer restricted parameters

Tags: distributions, bayesian, references, prior, uninformative-prior

Does anyone have advice/references on choosing a minimally informative prior for the shape parameter of an Erlang distribution (gamma distribution with shape parameter restricted to integer space), or a joint prior on both parameters.
My gut tells me that a discrete uniform could be a bad idea. A truncated poisson would work but will be quite informative....

Comment: I have never seen an Erlang-k application where k is not fixed. It will be hard to find references for what you are doing. Are you running a hierarchical model?

Comment: @joint_p nope not a hierarchical model.

Comment: Why don't you just run with different k-s and then do bayes factor? Or use a Dirichlet prior. I am not sure if there is any benefit to modeling the order of that integer. If you think that it's necessary, how about an ordered probit link? Just use a normal as prior, add cut-points and also put a prior on those.